# How to print listbox selection in order in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

I would like print selection from the listbox in the order I selected them, in tkinter.

```
def showSelected():
    statements = []
    cname = lb.curselection()
    for i in cname:
        op = lb.get(i)
        statements.append(op)
    for val in statements:
        print(val)

lb = Listbox(ws, selectmode = "multiple")
x =["apples", "bananas", "pineapple", "mangoes", "kiwi"]

for item in range(len(x)): 
    lb.insert(END, x[item]) 
    lb.itemconfig(item, bg="#bdc1d6") 

btn = Button(ws, text="Transpaste", command=showSelected).pack()
```

If I selected "pineapples" then "bananas", I wish to print first "pineapples" then "bananas".

What changes should I make to the showSelected function?

Answer (score 0):

The listbox doesn't support what you want to do. You'll have to make an implementation yourself. For example, you could add a binding for a button click and append the selected items to a list.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you can bind your Listbox Like this.

```
lb.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>",showSelected)
```